# How to display items that are in a linear layout into two columns

Tags: java, android-layout, kotlin, android-xml

I'm working on an application, and a section of the application displays selected items. For instance, languages. Right now, the languages are displayed in a linear layout where you can only have one item per line. I want to change it in a way where I can show 2 languages in one row. so that means two columns:

[image: I want to display it like that without the seperators]

Comment: Is it a fixed list of languages? Or dynamic, based on data?

Comment: No It's dynamic. Basically there's a card with languages displayed based on what the user edits in an edit fragment. So yeah based on data

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is dynamic, I recommend you use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`, and a `spanCount` of 2.

Your item layout is quite simple (just a TextView), but you can use this technique with more complex item layouts (e.g. cards, images + labels, etc.):

[image]

There are many steps, but it's something you will use a lot, and every RV follows the same pattern:

1. Layout for 1 item
2. RV ViewHolder (matching item layout)
3. Data Model (you can just use String)
4. RV Adapter (just follow the pattern)
5. Activity layout (with an RV)
6. Activity onCreate (to setup the adapter)

Note: there are 3 choices for the LayoutManager

- LinearLayoutManager
- GridLayoutManager *(we'll use this)*
- StaggeredGridLayoutManager

***1. item_language.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Width and Height must be wrap -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/languageName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/cities" />
        <!-- there are only a few @tools:sample choices available -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***2. LanguageViewHolder***

```
class LanguageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    // Matches views in item_language.xml
    private val languageName = itemView.languageName

    fun bind(language: String) {
        languageName.text = language
    }

}
```

***4. LanguagesAdapter***

```
class LanguagesAdapter(private val data: List<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LanguageViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_language, parent, false)
            .let { LanguageViewHolder(it) }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LanguageViewHolder, position: Int) =
        holder.bind(data[position])

}
```

***5. activity_my.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <!-- the rest of your layout -->

    <!-- set Orientation, LayoutManager, and SpanCount in your XML -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/languagesGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_language" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***6. MyActivity onCreate***

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid)

    val languages = listOf("English", "Chinese", "Spanish", "German", "French")
    languagesGrid.adapter = LanguagesAdapter(languages)
}
```

Comment: Could this be done using table layout and table rows?

Comment: It could, but because you don't know how many views you need, you'd need to create and manage them dynamically with code (which IMO is more effort than an RV).

Comment: @fxrzm - The designer only considers the 2 XML files. To make it work at runtime, you must also have all the Kotlin files. My guess is that you're missing a step, like setting the `Adapter` in `onCreate`. It's going to be pretty hard to remote debug; can you follow it in the runtime debugger? (get data > onCreate > Adapter > ViewHolder)

Comment: @fxrzm - Another possibility is that you are using ConstraintLayout, but your RV isn't properly constrained. If you're missing vertical or horizontal constraints the width or height might be zero. Also RVs don't seem to size properly inside Dialogs :/

Answer (score 0):

I this may help you.

```
    layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```